# Create JSON from the List using Json4s

Tags: scala, json4s

I have list of elements containing product name 
`val productList = List[String]` with values as `product1,product2,product3`

now I need to create a Json from the list as

```
{
   "ProductName":["product1","product2","product3"]
}
```

how can I achieve this using scala json4s framework.

Answer (score 3):

You may also try write method.

```
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.jackson.Serialization.write
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._
implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
val json = write(Map("productList" -> productList))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to render the list directly.  Json4s can implicitly convert a list of strings into a `JArray`, which then becomes a json list.

```
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.JsonDSL._
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._

val productList: List[String] = List("product1", "product2", "product3")
val obj: JObject = ("ProductName" -> productList)
compact(render(obj))
//res1: String = {"ProductList":["product1","product2","product3"]}
```

The [readme for Json4s](https://github.com/json4s/json4s) has some similar examples.